# How to avoid browser redirection while Automating the scripts using Selenide?

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, webdriver, selenide

While running my automation scripts, the browser is redirecting to the login page in the middle and I am not able to find anything in console from developer tools.

can someone help me in resolving this browser redirection and empty console ??

Comment: Could you provide a code example? Without it, it's very difficult to help you with your issue

Comment: My automation script is all good, but suddenly in the middle instead of performing the test it is getting redirected to the login page.. Is it because of MICROSOFT OUTLOOK ACCOUNT or anything else ??